# UNO-1019 development on Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sdk, evc

I'm trying to set up my developing environment using Visual Studio 2008 to develop for the UNO-1019. I managed to connect the UNO to VS for deployment and debug using the ethernet connection.

I installed the SDK for EVC++ available on the products page and I was wondering if I can use that sdk on visual studio 2008.I'm rather new with this and I's kind of lost.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this was me being dumb.

I downloaded and installed the Windows CE 5.0 SDK from here:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=FA1A3D66-3F61-4DDC-9510-AE450E2318C3&displaylang=en

I didn't realize that I could use that sdk. I was under the impression that I had to use the sdk provided by the manufacturer.